# Javascript undefined variable because of AJAX GET request

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have the following function. When I try to log the varible, it gives me undefined. I think it's because of the loading time from the AJAX GET call, but I don't know how to fix it.

EDIT: Yes, all the values are correct. The console.log logs the correct value, so everything within the function works. It's just the return that does not work.

Any ideas?

```
function loadOnderhoud() {  
    var username = window.sessionStorage.getItem("huidigeGebruiker");
    var url = "restservices/gebruiker?Q1=" + username;
        $.ajax({
            url : url,
            method : "GET",
            beforeSend : function(xhr) {
                var token = window.sessionStorage.getItem("sessionToken");
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
            },
            success : function(data) {
                var onderhoud;

                $(data).each(function (index) {
                    if (this.geslacht == "m"){
                        onderhoud = (66 + (13.7 * this.gewicht) + (5 * (this.lengte*100)) - (6.8 * this.leeftijd)) * this.activiteit;
                    }
                    else if (this.geslacht == "v"){
                        onderhoud = (655 + (9.6 * this.gewicht) + (1.8 * (this.lengte*100)) - (4.7 * this.leeftijd)) * this.activiteit;
                    }
                    });
                console.log(onderhoud);
                return onderhoud;
            },
        });
}


function loadAdviezen(){
    var onderhoud = loadOnderhoud();
}
```

Comment: success only executes once the ajax request is completed.

Comment: are you sure your response is returning the correct values?

Comment: Probably `this.geslacht` doesn't match either `m` or `v`...

Comment: @SabirAmeen Yes, it is succesful beacuse it does log. And it returns a double. All the values are correct, the function works.

Comment: are you sure onderhoud is getting initialized atleast once?

Comment: Could the #SO team add an *top duplicates for javascript* into the duplicate section?

Comment: this.geslacht value maybe incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is related to return from success function of ajax,

**Proper way** of doing is **Provide the call back function**:

```
function loadOnderhoud(getData) {  
    var username = window.sessionStorage.getItem("huidigeGebruiker");
    var url = "restservices/gebruiker?Q1=" + username;
        $.ajax({
            url : url,
            method : "GET",
            beforeSend : function(xhr) {
                var token = window.sessionStorage.getItem("sessionToken");
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
            },
            success : function(data) {
                var onderhoud;

                $(data).each(function (index) {
                    if (this.geslacht == "m"){
                        onderhoud = (66 + (13.7 * this.gewicht) + (5 * (this.lengte*100)) - (6.8 * this.leeftijd)) * this.activiteit;
                    }
                    else if (this.geslacht == "v"){
                        onderhoud = (655 + (9.6 * this.gewicht) + (1.8 * (this.lengte*100)) - (4.7 * this.leeftijd)) * this.activiteit;
                    }
                    });
                console.log(onderhoud);
                getData(onderhoud);
            },
        });
}

function getData(data)
{
    var onderhoud = data;
}
loadOnderhoud(getData);
```

Comment: The async false does not work, I'll try your second suggestion.

Comment: @Liam , yes I got your point answer was posted by mistake I was adding the second way also , my mistake :)

Comment: OKay I am removing it.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: getData is not defined

Comment: Do you have live demo ? or plunker ?

Comment: @SomeName, just forgot to add function before getData , please try now

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm.

Comment: Do you know how I would go about having 2 callbacks into 1 function? I have a function loadMacro() just like loadAdviezen(). I need both results in one function.

Comment: yes you can also pass 2 callbacks , same as getData , pass it as 2 parameters

Comment: I did that, but it gives me 4 results now. var1 + undefined and also var2+undefined.
function getData(data, dataa)
{
    var onderhoud = data;
    var macro = dataa;
    console.log(onderhoud, macro);
}
loadOnderhoud(getData);
loadMacro(getData);

Comment: Post that also as different question , just let me know after that :)

Comment: Thank you, edited the question.

Comment: @SomeName , this is not how stackoverflow works  man , please post different question for another query , your edit to the question makes answer invalid

Comment: Can't post for another 30mins. I'll post it when I can.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44570453/passing-2-callbacks-gives-undefined-as-result