# Passing 2 callbacks gives undefined as result

Tags: javascript, ajax

Q1: The callbacks both work, but I get 4 results instead of 2. I get onderhoud+undefined aswell as macro+undefined.

How do I solve this?

Q2: how do I pass all the variables from loadMacro in the callback and use them seperately in the callback?

```
function loadOnderhoud(getData) {  
    var username = window.sessionStorage.getItem("huidigeGebruiker");
    var url = "restservices/gebruiker?Q1=" + username;
        $.ajax({
            url : url,
            method : "GET",
            beforeSend : function(xhr) {
                var token = window.sessionStorage.getItem("sessionToken");
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
            },
            success : function(data) {
                var onderhoud;

                $(data).each(function (index) {
                    if (this.geslacht == "m"){
                        onderhoud = (66 + (13.7 * this.gewicht) + (5 * (this.lengte*100)) - (6.8 * this.leeftijd)) * this.activiteit;
                    }
                    else if (this.geslacht == "v"){
                        onderhoud = (655 + (9.6 * this.gewicht) + (1.8 * (this.lengte*100)) - (4.7 * this.leeftijd)) * this.activiteit;
                    }
                    });
                getData(onderhoud);
            },
        });
}

// Load ingredients from JSON test file
function loadMacro(getData) {   
    var username = window.sessionStorage.getItem("huidigeGebruiker");
    var datum = document.getElementById("datepicker").value;
    var url = "restservices/ingredients?Q1=" + username + "&Q2=" + datum;
        $.ajax({
            url : url,
            method : "GET",
            async: false,
            beforeSend : function(xhr) {
                var token = window.sessionStorage.getItem("sessionToken");
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
            },
            success : function(data) {
                 var totalCal=0;
                 var totalVet=0;
                 var totalVv=0;
                 var totalEiwit=0;
                 var totalKh=0;
                 var totalVezels=0;
                 var totalZout=0;
                $(data).each(function (index) {
                     totalCal = (this.hoeveelheid * this.calorieen) / 100;
                     totalVet = (this.hoeveelheid * this.vet) / 100;
                     totalVv = (this.hoeveelheid * this.verzadigd_vet) / 100;
                     totalEiwit = (this.hoeveelheid * this.eiwit) / 100;
                     totalKh = (this.hoeveelheid * this.koolhydraten) / 100;
                     totalVezels = (this.hoeveelheid * this.vezels) / 100;
                     totalZout = (this.hoeveelheid * this.zout) / 100;
                    });
                getData(totalCal);
            },
        });

}

function getData(data, dataa)
{
    var onderhoud = data;
    var macro = dataa;
    console.log(onderhoud, macro);
}
loadOnderhoud(getData);
loadMacro(getData);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works

```
var onderhoud;
var macro;
function loadOnderhoud(getData) {  
    var username = window.sessionStorage.getItem("huidigeGebruiker");
    var url = "restservices/gebruiker?Q1=" + username;
        $.ajax({
            url : url,
            method : "GET",
            beforeSend : function(xhr) {
                var token = window.sessionStorage.getItem("sessionToken");
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
            },
            success : function(data) {
                var onderhoud;

                $(data).each(function (index) {
                    if (this.geslacht == "m"){
                        onderhoud = (66 + (13.7 * this.gewicht) + (5 * (this.lengte*100)) - (6.8 * this.leeftijd)) * this.activiteit;
                    }
                    else if (this.geslacht == "v"){
                        onderhoud = (655 + (9.6 * this.gewicht) + (1.8 * (this.lengte*100)) - (4.7 * this.leeftijd)) * this.activiteit;
                    }
                    });
                getData(onderhoud);
            },
        });
}

// Load ingredients from JSON test file
function loadMacro(getData) {   
    var username = window.sessionStorage.getItem("huidigeGebruiker");
    var datum = document.getElementById("datepicker").value;
    var url = "restservices/ingredients?Q1=" + username + "&Q2=" + datum;
        $.ajax({
            url : url,
            method : "GET",
            async: false,
            beforeSend : function(xhr) {
                var token = window.sessionStorage.getItem("sessionToken");
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
            },
            success : function(data) {
                 var totalCal=0;
                 var totalVet=0;
                 var totalVv=0;
                 var totalEiwit=0;
                 var totalKh=0;
                 var totalVezels=0;
                 var totalZout=0;
                $(data).each(function (index) {
                     totalCal = (this.hoeveelheid * this.calorieen) / 100;
                     totalVet = (this.hoeveelheid * this.vet) / 100;
                     totalVv = (this.hoeveelheid * this.verzadigd_vet) / 100;
                     totalEiwit = (this.hoeveelheid * this.eiwit) / 100;
                     totalKh = (this.hoeveelheid * this.koolhydraten) / 100;
                     totalVezels = (this.hoeveelheid * this.vezels) / 100;
                     totalZout = (this.hoeveelheid * this.zout) / 100;
                    });
                getData(totalCal);
            },
        });

}

function getData(data)
{
    onderhoud = data;
}
function getData2(data)
{
    macro = data;
}
loadOnderhoud(getData);
loadMacro(getData2);
```

Comment: If I want both variables in 1 function, is my best option to declare the variables global and set them within the getData? Or is there a better way? Also, could you tell me how I can get all the variables within the each function from loadMacro()? Thank you very much!

Comment: in that case you need to create a chain of ajax calls , one after another ajax call not asyncronous

Comment: Doing this I still can't use the data outside of the getData function. The whole point is to have all information together in 1 function. I tried to declare the variable outside the getData function and set it inside the function, but this gives me undefined again.

Comment: for that you have to define those varible outside the function